# MONDRIAN: Flushing the dimension cache

Tags: java, data-warehouse, mondrian

I've read this in [the Mondrian documentation](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/cache_control.php#Flushing_the_dimension_cache):

> Flushing the dimension cache
>
> An application might also want to make modifications to a dimension table. Mondrian does not currently allow an application to control the cache of members...

I have a warehouse with dynamic dimensions.  I've tried `flushMember(Member, boolean children)` or `flushMembers(CellRegion)`, in order to accomplish the flushing, with no success (maybe I don't know how to call them).

I'm using mondrian 3.0.4, so my question is: do the newer versions of the mondrian API have support for flushing the dimension cache, painlessly?

Or is there any way to do it in mondrian 3.0.4?

Comment: Are you using these APIs in a JSP servlet or a standalone Java class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flushing the entire schema cache worked for me due there is no way to do it just for the members. Disabling the cache mechanisms in the cube schema was too invasive and had huge performance issues.

```
CacheControl.flushSchema(catalogSchema);
```

Comment: From where should we call this method?

Answer (score 1):

You can always set the `cache="false"` on your `<Cube>` element in your XML definition.

Answer (score 0):

According to the article that you linked to:

> Mondrian does not currently allow an application to control the cache of members

You even included this in your citation(!).

It's unambiguous, you can't do it at present (at least not in an officially supported way).  The methods you mentioned were, as I understood it, examples of the sort of API that might be offered when this functionality is added in future.  They don't currently exist.